# Fix height to smallest possible GTK

Tags: gtk, layout-manager

I have placed buttons inside a horizontal box inside a window. Now I want this box to be on the top of the window with the smallest possible height. The rest of the window is drawing area for an image display that changes height with the window. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a table with the following for the first and second row

```
gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table),toolbar,0,1,0,1
    ,GtkAttachOptions((guint)GTK_FILL|(guint)GTK_EXPAND)
    ,GTK_SHRINK,0,0);

gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table),test,0,1,1,2
    ,GtkAttachOptions((guint)GTK_FILL|(guint)GTK_EXPAND)
    ,GtkAttachOptions((guint)GTK_FILL|(guint)GTK_EXPAND),0,0);
```

Comment: Use a vertical box instead of a `GtkTable`.